# How do I choose the disk to install macOS Sierra?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos

I'm so new to macbook and I just download and update macOS to the latest version and it's not able to complete the installation. However I manage to get to the recovery mode but there's still a problem.

When I select install macOS on the recovery mode, I am asked to choose the disk but I couldn't select Macintosh HD as it said,

> 'You may not install to this volume because it is currently being
>   encrypted'

How do I fix this? Please help

Thank you [image]

Comment: The question answers itself.  *It's being encrypted* means *it's in the processing of being encrypted.*  You must have selected FileVault encryption during your installation and now you must wait for it to complete.

Comment: Take a look at [this guide to updating your OS](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/macos-installation-issues-fix-common-mac-upgrade-problems/).  If you're new to this, having a guide like this will be helpful, especially the "backup everything first" suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how good this may work, but once you boot into recovery mode, from the menu bar on the top, under `Utilities` you should find `Disk Utility`. Once you open disk utility, select the disk you want to install the OS on, and then click the `Mount` option, this should give you a prompt to provide the password to unlock the drive.

Once you have successfully unlocked and mounted the drive, quit Disk Utilities, and the default window with the option to install macOS should come back, from thereon you may continue with the installation as usual.

I didn't have the opportunity to boot in Recovery mode and make sure this works, so your milage may vary. Also, I would highly suggest you take a look at the guide posted by one of the comments, as well as make a back up of everything important in that drive before you proceed with this! Good luck!